# LARAVEL 5.4 access User obj from other class

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

How to have access to a user object from the instance of another object ?
I can access the *projects* of a user but not the *author* of the project.

This :

```
$user_id = App\Project::find(1)->user_id;
$user = App\User::find($user_id);
```

returns a user

but this :

```
$user  = App\Project::find(1)->author;
```

returns null

Expected behaviour : get the user

the User class :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password'
];

protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}
}
```

the Project class:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'content'
];

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}

public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
}
```

Comment: what return `App\Project::find(1)->user_id;` null or a number?

Comment: it returns a number

Comment: I replaced the method author() by user() and now it's fine

Comment: `author(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\Post', 'user_id');` or it search for a author_id

Comment: ok thanks  a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Project model change this:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

to this:

```
public function author()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

Laravel search for a foreign key named as the relation name plus `_id`, in your code it searchs for a `author_id`, if you add a second argument you change this to search for `user_id`